# Can't seek in streamed file

Tags: python, html, http, audio, streaming

I have developed a server that serves audio files over HTTP. Using the Content-Length header I was able to view the current position, but this source isn't seekable. How can I make it seekable? 
Some people recommended sending Accept-Range: bytes, but when I tried that the audio doesn't even play anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Think about what you're asking: A stream of bytes is arriving over the network, and you want random access over it? You can't. What you *can* do is implement buffering yourself, which you could do reasonably transparently with the `io` module. If you want to seek forward, discard the intermediate blocks; if you want to seek backward, you'll have to hold the stream in memory till you don't need it anymore.

If you don't want to buffer the entire stream client-side, you need a way to tell the *server* to seek to a different position and restart streaming from there.